# XGBoost model performance barely budging, and max_depth is basically irrelevant

Tags: machine-learning, python, xgboost

I have a dataset that includes 62 features and around 1 million observations. The 62 features are mostly socioeconomic status indicators for students as they start a school year. The labels are the students grade in the next school year. My goal is to help identify students at the beginning of the year who will perform poorly, and then give them access to additional resources to prevent poor grades. More specifically, my goal is to properly predict which students will be in the bottom 3%ile of grades in coming school year. The magnitude of errors is important - if I predict a student will be in the bottom 3% and the student ends up being an A+ student, that is very costly to me. For this reason, I tried making an XGBoost regression (since classification doesn't punish wildly wrong answers).

However, my results so far have been disappointing. My features are either percentile data (continuous from 0 to 1) or binary. My labels are percentile data (continuous from zero 1). It seems that no matter which hyperparameters I adjust, the RMSE starts at 0.28 and barely budges from there. Here is the model with output for max_depth = 1.

```
#Regression Model
params = {
  'tree_method' : 'exact',
  'min_split_loss':5,
  'colsample_bynode':0.5,
  'reg_lambda':20,
  'reg_alpha':100,
  'subsample':0.5,
  'learning_rate': 0.3,
  'max_depth':1,
  'objective': 'reg:squarederror',
  'verbosity':0,
  }
watchlist = [(train, 'train'), (test, 'val')]
reg = xgb.train(params, train, num_boost_round=100, early_stopping_rounds=3, evals=watchlist)

[0] train-rmse:0.281513 val-rmse:0.28249
Multiple eval metrics have been passed: 'val-rmse' will be used for early stopping.

Will train until val-rmse hasn't improved in 3 rounds.
[1] train-rmse:0.281126 val-rmse:0.282324
[2] train-rmse:0.280893 val-rmse:0.282113
[3] train-rmse:0.280809 val-rmse:0.281991
[4] train-rmse:0.280657 val-rmse:0.281931
[5] train-rmse:0.280601 val-rmse:0.281875
[6] train-rmse:0.280551 val-rmse:0.281833
[7] train-rmse:0.280432 val-rmse:0.281818
[8] train-rmse:0.28036  val-rmse:0.28174
[9] train-rmse:0.28033  val-rmse:0.281737
[10]    train-rmse:0.280312 val-rmse:0.281732
[11]    train-rmse:0.280273 val-rmse:0.281694
[12]    train-rmse:0.280262 val-rmse:0.281682
[13]    train-rmse:0.280207 val-rmse:0.28168
[14]    train-rmse:0.280184 val-rmse:0.281649
[15]    train-rmse:0.28017  val-rmse:0.281634
[16]    train-rmse:0.280159 val-rmse:0.281638
[17]    train-rmse:0.280128 val-rmse:0.281641
[18]    train-rmse:0.280114 val-rmse:0.281637
Stopping. Best iteration:
[15]    train-rmse:0.28017  val-rmse:0.281634
```

And here is the output when I increase to max_depth = 6:

```
[0] train-rmse:0.281331 val-rmse:0.282431
Multiple eval metrics have been passed: 'val-rmse' will be used for early stopping.

Will train until val-rmse hasn't improved in 3 rounds.
[1] train-rmse:0.280839 val-rmse:0.282097
[2] train-rmse:0.280446 val-rmse:0.281867
[3] train-rmse:0.280329 val-rmse:0.281756
[4] train-rmse:0.280185 val-rmse:0.281703
[5] train-rmse:0.280153 val-rmse:0.281693
[6] train-rmse:0.280151 val-rmse:0.281695
[7] train-rmse:0.280106 val-rmse:0.281692
[8] train-rmse:0.280081 val-rmse:0.28167
[9] train-rmse:0.280081 val-rmse:0.281671
[10]    train-rmse:0.28008  val-rmse:0.281672
[11]    train-rmse:0.280062 val-rmse:0.281654
[12]    train-rmse:0.280062 val-rmse:0.281654
[13]    train-rmse:0.280025 val-rmse:0.281638
[14]    train-rmse:0.280025 val-rmse:0.281638
[15]    train-rmse:0.280025 val-rmse:0.281638
[16]    train-rmse:0.280014 val-rmse:0.281642
Stopping. Best iteration:
[13]    train-rmse:0.280025 val-rmse:0.281638
```

It doesn't make sense to me that a max_depth of 1 yields virtually the same results as max_depth = 6, when I have 62 features... Also the RMSE at 0.28 isn't much better than just random, which would be around 0.4. I feel like there is something blatantly wrong given max_depth is essentially irrelevant.

Does anyone have some advice to improve the performance? Or perhaps a different machine learning technique rather than regression?

Comment: Do you have some "baseline" model, e.g. linear regression or lasso. Since your model seems to learn nothing at all, there might be a problem with your model setup. A baseline model could help to understand what you can expect and how to proceed.

Comment: No, I will make a linear regression ASAP and report back.

Comment: @Peter the R^2 of the linear regression model is 0.0049

Comment: Okay, this is bad! So it seems that your features (as they are) explain very little of the actual variation in the data. So the XGB results are reasonable. How did you tune the hyperparameter? You could use Bayesian Optimization to find the best parameters. Here is an example with Catboost: https://github.com/Bixi81/Python-ml/blob/master/Catboost_bayesian_opt_parameter_search.py

Comment: Given the nature of the dataset, it should be difficult and I'm not aiming for RMSE < 0.01. However, RMSE at 0.28 is not much different than random guesses. There certainly is some predictive power as I have made a man-made linear regression model that works better.

I tuned hyperparameter with simple grid_search - no hyperparameter changes have any significant effect on RMSE, always just spits out something in the 0.28 - 0.285 range.

Comment: Not knowing the problem/data in detail, I guess you would need to look into redefining the model and feature engineering. However, it is well possible that you will not be able to make good predictions since "ability" of people is unobserved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109576/discussion-between-xxanissrxx-and-peter).